# Extract string with specific format

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm novice to Python and I am trying to extract a string from another string with specific format, for example:

I have original string: -

```
--@$_ABC1234-XX12X
```

I need to extract exactly the string `ABC1234` (must include three first characters and followed by four digits).

Comment: Any attempts thus far? It is generally frowned upon to ask questions without first attempting something.

Comment: So you want to check if the string `ABC1234` is in the original string? Or you want to get the three characters before it and the four characters after it?

Comment: I already tried but still couldn't get success. I want to get exactly the string ABC1234 from the original string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the curly brace [repetition qualifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) `{}` to match exactly three alphabetic characters and exactly four numeric characters:

```
>>> from re import search
>>> 
>>> string = '---@$_ABC1234-XX12X'
>>> match = search('[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{4}', string)
>>> match
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(6, 13), match='ABC1234'>
>>> match.group(0) # Use this to get the string that was matched.
'ABC1234'
```

Explanation of regex:

- `[a-zA-Z]`: Match any letter upper case of lower case...
- `{3}`: Exactly three times. And...
- `\d`: Any digit character...
- `{4}` Exactly four times.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't get it with regex

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `re` module in Python

```
matcher = re.search((?P<matched_string>[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{4}))
needed_string = matcher.groupdict()['matched_string']
```

`needed_string` will be your desired output.

For the `re` module refer to: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

If you now the exact coordinates of the string you can use something like this:

```
>>> var = "--@$_ABC1234-XX12X"
>>> newstring = var[5:12]
>>> newstring
'ABC1234'
```

a python string has a slice method.

Comment: Thanks. But I prefer the search method the position of strings should be flexible.