# Extract specific format from a string, regex, python

Tags: python, regex, string

***DESCRIPTION:***

I have a string with a word, a number, bracket, and a letter inside the bracket.

***QUESTION:***

I want to extract only the numbers with decimal and the bracket with a letter in it.

***EXAMPLE:***

```
, INC., 5.5(b) -------> 5.5(b)

Section 13.2(k)(ii) ---------> 13.2(k)(ii)

WBNEOGNOFD.)! 82.3(b)(k)(ix) -----------> 82.3(b)(k)(ix)
```

***ATTEMPT I MADE:***

Find the first number then the decimal, followed by '('. But, sometimes, its only 1 number and no brackets after the decimal.

***SOLUTION I THINK WOULD SOLVE BUT I COULD NOT SOLVE IT:***

curly brace repetition qualifiers {} to match exactly three alphabetic characters and exactly four numeric characters.
I tried the answer given by Christian Dean to solve for my regex, but it did not give an accurate result. ([Extract string with specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45136598/extract-string-with-specific-format))

Comment: When there are no brackets after the decimal, do you want a match or not?

Comment: please share the regex you tried

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Anything would work. To match it or not, unless it can identify that pattern.

Comment: @depperm: search('\d.\d{2}([a-zA-Z])', string). We use /d to find any digit, what do we use to identify a decimal, or a bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match digits with decimals followed by groups of `()`s, you can use

```
\d+\.\d+(?:\(\w+\))+
```

https://regex101.com/r/wqYZr9/1

- `\d+\.\d+` - Match a decimal number
- `(?:\(\w+\))+` - Repeat a group of word characters in parentheses

Comment: Is it possible to extract a single digit?

Comment: You mean, don't match decimal numbers or numbers greater than 9? I guess you could lookbehind for a space or the start of the string or something, something like `(?<= )\d(?:\(\w+\))+` Not sure exactly what you're looking for

Comment: For example, using your regex, I could not extract if the string was "Article 7". Is it possible to extract that '7', if the string has no decimal and only a digit?

Comment: If the string contains only a single digit and you want to match that digit, just use `\d`

Comment: Yeah. But what if it needs either a single digit or a group of it (Just the way it is described above)?

Comment: Do I need to combine two regex: One for digit and other for sequence and valuate it in "if" to detect if it is a single digit or a sequence and define different functions for both the pattern?

Comment: I think I got it. \d+\.\d+(?:\(\w+\))+|\d. Is this correct?

Comment: I don't know what the input strings can be like, it's hard to say.The regex101 matches `Article 13.2(k)(ii)` just as it matches `Section 13.2(k)(ii)`. If you want only a single digit after `Article`, leave off the `\.\d+` to match only whole numbers like 13.